# Slime Farm Lighting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm creating a large slime farm of 3 connected chunks, I know that for this project to work I need to light up the spawning platforms but I don't know which method to light them.

I understand that torches will block spawning spaces, but I don't know if glowstone can spawn mobs on it.

Comment: _Nothing_ spawns on glowstone because it is a "transparent" block.

Comment: @Mutantoe then what lighting blocks could I use? Sea lanterns or jack-o-lanterns?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as the floor isn't made of "transparent" blocks. There's a list here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Opacity

Comment: The "no torches" rule is at least partially invalid in Minecraft 1.8. The spawning algorithm *can* start on blocks with no hitbox, such as rails, grass, fire and torches, and mobs were always able to spawn inside them. I am unsure about pack spawning however, which might still require an actual air-block to start the spawning cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big [Slimes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime) need 2.5 high to spawn and 3.5 to jump, so you should go for half slabs as platforms. For lighting use jack o' lanterns (much cheaper then sea lanterns, but you can use both), so that there isn't any spot in a platform that has light 7 or less because

> the light level of the spawning block must be 7 or darker (with exception during thunderstorms), and more light increases the chance that the spawn will fail

from [spawn conditions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Spawn_conditions)